# Passenger-irb --debug <PID> fails to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have Passenger-Enterprise installed on a production server so I can have access to `passenger-irb`. I am following the instructions found on this documentation here [Passenger with Nginx Debugger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/debugging_console/ruby/)

Here is the contents of my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'activeadmin', '1.0.0'
gem 'airbrake', '~> 5.5'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0' # paperclip doesn't work with the new aws-sdk gem
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'brakeman'
gem 'byebug', platforms: :ruby_20
gem 'bundler-audit'
gem 'coffee-rails'
```

As you can see, I have `byebug` correctly installed. The problems begin when I follow the next step.

In my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file, I place the `passenger_debbuger on;` option.

restarting nginx/passenger with this option on immediately kills all passenger processes. When I inspect the `error.log` file, I see the following error:

```
[ E 2017-10-20 16:20:20.3577 31875/Tr 

age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:289 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/local/openhub/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
   9   Error ID: 34c68141
  10   Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-CXx53h.html
  11   Message from application: cannot load such file -- byebug (LoadError)
  12   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:346:in `require'
  13   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:346:in `load_byebug_gem'
  14   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:326:in `before_loading_app_code_step2'
  15   /usr/share/passenger-enterprise/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:85:in `preload_app'
  16   /usr/share/passenger-enterprise/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:140:in `<module:App>'
  17   /usr/share/passenger-enterprise/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:14:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  18   /usr/share/passenger-enterprise/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I'm at a loss as to what to try to do at this point. Passenger does not have any documentation anywhere as to how to troubleshoot. I've followed the directions exactly but the passenger_debugger option is not working properly. Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Which ruby version are you using exactly?

Comment: I have 2.2.5 installed

Comment: Try using `gem 'byebug'` instead of `gem 'byebug', platforms: :ruby_20` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Did removing the platform restriction help?